# Flask rendering templates wit multiple variables

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

In main template I'm filling the data in the html form, and than I try to render template with multiple data which i receive from my main template.

```
def pay_post(self):
        data = EuroResource.pay_data(self)
        # return render_template('pay_eur.html', **data)
        return render_template('pay_eur.html', payer_currency=data['payer_currency'], shop_amount=data['shop_amount'], shop_currency=data["shop_currency"], shop_id=data["shop_id"], shop_order_id=data["shop_order_id"], sign=data["sign"])
```

But unfortunately data didn't rendering in my new template and it didn't rediret from main page to pay_eur.html.
I'm not understand why my templates isn't rendering.

This is a piece of my template form

```
<form name="Pay" method="post" action=" https://pay.piastrix.com/ru/pay">
           <input name="payer_currency" value={{ payer_currency }}/>
           <input name="shop_amount" value={{ shop_amount }}/>
           <input type="submit" value="Confirm"/>
       </form>
``
```

Comment: `data` in your code might be `None`. Debug your view, set a breakpoint after you get `data` and check if it has some value.

Comment: I checked and data is not None

Comment: Maybe you forgot to add route mapping for this function. If the function has a route, it should either return a new template or give an error. If you get an error, please provide the stack trace

Comment: Well, If your `data` dict has key `payer_currency` with value, then in your template `payer_currency` should be rendering. Please check if you are using the correct convention to use a variable in tamplate. e.g: `{{payer_currency}}`.

Comment: share your template as well if still you are facing the issue.

Comment: I added a piece of my template